# how do i destroy variables in vb.net formUI?

Tags: vb.net, forms, user-interface, variables

I have written some code in visual studio using vb.net and I was just wondering how do I destroy variables when the program exits.

Here is my code for the first form(Login):

```
Public Class LoginForm1
'username variables 
Public username1 As String
Public username2 As String
Public username3 As String
'Password variables 
Public pwd1 As String
Public pwd2 As String
Public pwd3 As String

'user input variables 
Public userInputUsername As String
Public userInputPwd As String

'switch form variable
Public correctLoginForm As New correctLogin
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    'setting usernames and passwords
    username1 = "Chops"
    username2 = "Jeff"
    username3 = "Bob"

    pwd1 = "Cheese"
    pwd2 = "Sign"
    pwd3 = "Speaker"

    'set user input variables
    userInputUsername = TextBox1.Text
    userInputPwd = TextBox2.Text

    'test for correct username/pwd
    If userInputUsername = username1 And userInputPwd = pwd1 Then
        correctLoginForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    ElseIf userInputUsername = username2 And userInputPwd = pwd2 Then
        correctLoginForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    ElseIf userInputUsername = username3 And userInputPwd = pwd3 Then
        correctLoginForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    Else
        Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red

    End If

End Sub
```

this is the image of my first form (as above)
[my first form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCHWJ.png)

I wanted to remove the variables so that I could free up space in ram

Comment: Hi. When your program terminates, the operating system will remove it from memory, and it should do so completely, even if you have internal memory leaks. Perhaps I should ask why you think you need to do anything at program exit? If you tell us that, there might be other considerations you need to make, but rest assured that unless you manage to trip an OS bug, your program should not leak memory permanently after it has exited.

Comment: You probably would benefit from reading a book on how operating systems work. Unless you can show you have a programming issue then there is nothing that we can help you with.

Comment: I was just wondering if I needed to destroy variables

Comment: @ChopsKingsland - Not if you're exiting your application.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help

Comment: You are doing `Me.Hide` which means variables `LoginForm1` still stay in memory. I suppose you cant go with `Me.Close` ??

Comment: @programerAnel what about application.exit()?

Comment: @ChopsKingsland the point is what i see here when you click on login you want to show the `correctLoginForm` and dispose the `LoginForm1` am i right ?

Comment: @programerAnel yes

Comment: That way `Application.exit()` will release the complete application `.exe` file and all corresponding forms. That was a bit tricky. At this time the only thing i have in mind is to go with another exe which will accept the correct parameters. So after you validate the login details you will run the other .exe file and close login one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are trying to free up memory and if this is the example then , I would not worry too much about garbage collection which is the freeing up of memory by disposing of unneeded data.

If the correctLogin is a class that is inherit of a form then you can simply dispose the variable correctLoginForm with .dispose, you can also set it to nothing but if you do remember to create a new instance of it or else you will get an object of of reference error.

For integers and strings ect. you can simple set them to nothing , but the memory savings on doing this are non existence, but it is still get practice especially if you are reusing the data and do not want contamination of old data into new records.

Comment: You could also use the ERASE function.